# Connecting to JMS queue hosted on IBM WAS from a spring boot app hosted on cloudfoundry for SOAP over JMS channel for Apache CXF

Tags: java, spring, jms, cxf, cloud-foundry

Hi all Im stuck at a peculiar spot. I am working on deploying a `SOAP` over `JMS` webservice to cloudfoundry. It is to be built using spring boot.
The `JMS Queue` is hosted on `IBM WAS 8.5`. I cant figure out how to specify the destination in the `org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfiguration`. 
typical jndi definition will work like below

```
<bean id="jmsConfig"
    class="org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfiguration"
    p:connectionFactory-ref="jmsConnectionFactoryX10"
    p:targetDestination="${Queue.baseQueueName.AccountOpening.JNDIName}"
    p:concurrentConsumers="5" 
    p:maxConcurrentConsumers="10" 
    p:receiveTimeout="30000" >
     <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestResolver" />
     <property name="reconnectOnException" value="false"/> 
</bean>
```

I am not sure that this will work. unfortunatley i dont have the luxury of pushing my build on cloudfoundry and testing because i dont have the env. That is stuck in some managerial redtape at my org and i dont want to wait till that is sorted. I have created the connection factory and destinationResolver beans.

Has any one faced similiar issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: other beans @Bean(name = "jmsQueueConnectionFactory")
 public UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter jmsQueueConnectionFactory() {
  UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter factoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
  factoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory());
  factoryAdapter.setUsername("${QueueConnectionFactory.X10.userName}");
  factoryAdapter.setPassword("${QueueConnectionFactory.X10.password}");
  return factoryAdapter;
 }

Comment: @Bean(name = "mqConnectionFactory")
 public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory() {
  MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
  try {
   factory.setHostName(hostName);
   factory.setPort(port);
   factory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
   factory.setChannel(channel);
   factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
   // factory.setSSLCipherSuite("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA");
   // factory.setSSLFipsRequired(false);

  } catch (JMSException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  return factory;
 }

Comment: @Bean(name = "jmsDestinationResolver")
 public JndiDestinationResolver jmsDestinationResolver() {
  JndiDestinationResolver jndiDestinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();
  jndiDestinationResolver.setResourceRef(Boolean.TRUE);
  jndiDestinationResolver.setCache(Boolean.TRUE);
  return jndiDestinationResolver;
 }

Comment: Please sue the "Edit" feature to add more information to your question. Code in comments is almost impossible to read properly.